# Define fields with data from a combo box [infopath]

Tags: c#

I want to set the value of some fields via a check box. My problem is because I can just pull a value, but I need to set all the values ​​of the selected object.

Comment: I do not understand your question. You pull ONE value from the check box, but then want to set MULTIPLE values into MULTIPLE fields of one of MANY objects?

Answer (score 0):

**DISCLAIMER:** when you put no effort into the question -you get an abstract answer like this.

OK, so if you're needing to set the values of the `SelectedObject` then you might do something like this:

```
ClassA o = combo.SelectedObject as ClassA;
o.PropertyA = newValueFromSomewhere1;
o.PropertyB = newValueFromSomewhere2;
```

and that's assuming a class like this:

```
public class ClassA
{
    public string PropertyA { get; set; }
    public string PropertyB { get; set; }
}
```

you of course need to fit that to your object.